# Access each element of the object in array (vue + ts)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at Proxy.render (form1.vue?4692:190:1)
    at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:893:1)


form1.vue?4692:190 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at Proxy.render (form1.vue?4692:190:1)
    at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:893:1)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:5030:1)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:160:1)
```

Error Occurred

```
<input
 type="text"
 class="form-control"
 v-model="data['item3'][0].item1"
/>
```

data to:

```
item3: [
      {
        item1: 'SSS',
        item2: [{ item3: '2' }],
        item3: '',
        item4: '2',
        item5: '',
        item6: '',
        item7: '',
        item8: '',
        item9: '',
        item10: '1',
        item11: '1',
      },
    ],
```

vue page data to:

```
const data = ref<any>({});

onMounted(() => {
  data.value = props.modelValue;
  if (!data.value['sheetname']) {
    data.value = new E507().data;
    data.value.sheetname = props.sheet.templatename;
  }
  console.log(data.value);
});
```

data['item3'][0] Inaccessible.
data['item3']?.[0]
I couldn't do v-model in binding.

Is there a way to access the 0th object?

Comment: Can you share what your `data` looks like?

Comment: @Rajesh data to: 
`
item3: [
      {
        item1: 'SSS',
        item2: [{ item3: '2' }],
        item3: '',
        item4: '2',
        item5: '',
        item6: '',
        item7: '',
        item8: '',
        item9: '',
        item10: '1',
        item11: '1',
      },
    ],
`

Answer (score 1):

As per your `data` object, `v-model` should be `item3[0].item1` instead of `data['item3'][0].item1`

Live Demo **:**

```js
const vm = {
  data() {
    return {
      item3: [{
        item1: 'SSS',
        item2: [{
          item3: '2'
        }],
        item3: '',
        item4: '2',
        item5: '',
        item6: '',
        item7: '',
        item8: '',
        item9: '',
        item10: '1',
        item11: '1',
      }]
    }
  }
}

Vue.createApp(vm).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.0.1/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input
         type="text"
         class="form-control"
         v-model="item3[0].item1"
         />
</div>
```

***Update :*** As you are using composition API, above answer will not work as it is using Options API. Here is the fix for composition API.

As we are updating the reference in the mounted hook, It will not load before the template render. Hence, Adding `v-if="data.item3"` in the `input` element will fix this issue.

Demo **:**

```js
const { ref, onMounted } = Vue;

const vm = {
setup: function () {
    let data = ref({});
    onMounted(()=>{
      data.value = {
        item3: [{
          item1: 'SSS',
          item2: [{
            item3: '2'
          }],
          item3: '',
          item4: '2',
          item5: '',
          item6: '',
          item7: '',
          item8: '',
          item9: '',
          item10: '1',
          item11: '1'
        }]
      }
    })
    return {
      data
    }    
  }
}

Vue.createApp(vm).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.0.1/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<input
         v-if="data.item3"
         type="text"
         class="form-control"
         v-model="data['item3'][0].item1"
         />
</div>
```

Comment: He is using the composition API not the options API. His data object is a custom ref not the top level Vue data object.

Comment: Because this is not an accurate reflection of how the OP's code works. The `data` object being referenced in the model is not the top level Vue `data` object but a custom `ref` (he is using the Vue composition API).

Comment: @knary After spending some time, I updated my answer with the solution based on composition API. If possible can you please revert your downvote now.